# jQuery Mobile Form Handling in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I've created a jQuery Mobile form that is used for creating 'user' models. The form posts back all the information correctly, however I am not sure how to handle the success and failure cases in the action for the corresponding controller. I would typically use:

```
# POST /user
def create
  @user = User.create(params[:user])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.mobile { @user.valid? ? redirect_to(root_url) : render(action: 'new') }
  end
end
```

However this causes strange animations in the jQuery Mobile (i.e. slides the screen out on errors). Any ideas how I I should be rendering out the errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about mobile phones, but if this is basically an ajax request, then you need to return `@user.errors.to_json` when something went wrong. If it's just a normal page request, then you can iterate over `@user.errors` in your view to display the errors however you want.

I also wouldn't recommend using the ? : operator inside of your `format.mobile` block. Do an `if` statement within the `respond_to` and outside of your individual format blocks so that you don't have to use the ? : operator over and over again as you add more format blocks. If you had 3 format blocks, you'd have 3 ? : statements rather than just 1 if.

If you only plan on using 1 type of format, you can use `respond_with` inside of the `create` action, and then use `respond_to :mobile` at the top of the controller. You should do this by default since it just works and it cleans up your controller actions.

Also, you don't want to call `User.create` right away. You should rather use `User.new` and then call `@user.save` on it in your main `if` statement to determine what to do on errors. This removes the call of `@user.valid?` and I think is more idiomatically correct.